# Django runserver under alias

Tags: django

I have been developing an application in Django. The production version of the app is running on an Apache server in a unix system. In order to get my app to play nicely with over applications running on the server, I had to create a WSGIScriptAlias (so on the production server www.example.com/home became www.example.com/alias/home). This change initially broke a few links and AJAX calls where the urls were a little too hard coded, but I think I've weeded out those issues.

However, for testing purposes and so that my development environment more closely reflects the production system, I would like to be able to alias the dev server as well. Is there any way to do this short of setting up an apache on my dev machine as well? `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000/alias` does not seem to work.

Comment: you can try running your application on different port "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8090 --settings=<producion settings>", why is there a need of alias?

Comment: the alias is necessary on the production server because there are other php projects sharing it. Without an alias, my django project eats up those urls and returns 404s. It would be nice to alias the dev server too because the alias on the production server causes some misdirected links. It would be easier to test and make sure those issues don't resurface if the dev server urls mirrored the production ones.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Take a look at [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/555955/can-i-configure-apache-mod-wsgi-so-that-the-alias-url-path-is-not-stripped-befor "this answer")